# Downloading video files with a larger size

Tags: vb.net, download, webclient

I have developed a movie website and I have it hosted in a private webserver.

I had also developed a windows app through which I wanna download my movies from my site.

The movies are of file size 400mb to 700mb. I tried using WebClient but it doesn't works for large file sizes.

private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
        try

        {

            WebClient wb = new WebClient();
            wb.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            wb.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Loading");
            wb.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://www.mysite.com/2D MOVIES/ColdSteel.mkv"), "D:\\ren.mkv");
            wb.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(wb_DownloadProgressChanged);
            wb.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(wb_DownloadFileCompleted);
        }
```

catch (WebException ex)

{

MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.ToString());

}

}

I'm a newbie so please guide me with code snippets in what way I can make it happen. I need the whole movie to be downloaded.

Anyone know how to implement this?

Comment: I tried using WebClient DownloadFileAysnc and as well as DownloadData but it works fine for small files when i request 300mb file it downloads 30-60mb and stops without throwing any exceptions!

Answer (score 0):

Did you see [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21053/MyDownloader-A-Multi-thread-C-Segmented-Download-M)? I think it can be good and it is open source.

Comment: Hi Shafiee.. I already tried that, but it downloads only 40-60mb of a whole 400mb file..